# Why does my camera start rotating randomly when following a path?

Tags: camera, bezier-curves, constraints

I have a camera that follows a bezier curve with a *Follow Path* constraint, with a *Track To* constraint that follows an object (named "Viewer") moving on another bezier curve with another *Follow Path* constraint. Everything works out perfectly fine with the camera's rotation for the entire path, until this part where the bezier curve does a loop. Once the camera reaches towards the top of the loop, the camera just rotates randomly, and no longer looks at the object. It still follows the curve, except refuses to look at the object which it's supposed to track. Once it reaches the bottom of the loop, everything returns back to normal. I've already tried clearing the curves' tilt. What am I doing wrong here?

As you can see in the picture below, the camera is facing down, when it's supposed to face torwards the object (you can't see the object since it's only a single edge).

[image]

Please download the .blend file, my explanation might not be enough for you to understand. Just enter the track camera view and play the animation from the beginning. Once it reaches the loop, you'll see what I mean. I appreciate any help in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix can be as follows:

Select your target object edge (Or duplicate it). Press <kbd>P</kbd> *> Separate by Selection* which will create a new object. Select both objects (Your old object and newly created object)

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to add both objects in a group so that they move as a single object.
Now you may lock the camera view to your new object.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the "Copy Rotation" constraint on the camera and it seems to work fine. You are copying the rotation of the Viewer object but I don't think it's actually rotating, so in the loop it confuses the camera.